# Viewing Permissions in Mac OS on a Windows Server 2016 using Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, mac-osx, windows-server-2016, file-permissions, mac

I am logging into a Windows Server 2016 server and then accessing several volumes.  While browsing directories in terminal, all file permissions appear as being owned by the PAM user I am logged into on the Mac workstation and the group is always staff.  The permissions are always displayed as set to 700 (rwx --- ---) for all files. When viewing permissions through the Mac Os user interface (right-click and "Get Info") the permissions always show up as saying simply "You have custom access".

I'm sure that this user did not create those files, as it's a new user account that has not created any files on the server. The logged in user's PAM credentials are not used to log into the SMB server but another set of username / password credentials are setup on the Windows 2016 Server.

I have two questions.

1) What are the best documents to read about networking Mac workstations and Windows Server 2016 (SMB file sharing) using Active Directory.  I have searched the internet and not found much documentation.  I want to understand differences between file permissions in Unix/Linux and Windows NTFS, and all the options available in terms of setting permissions and owner/group for files when they are created on a folder by folder basis in Windows Server.

2) Why would the permissions always show up as mentioned above in Mac terminal and "Get Info"?  Is there any other way to view more detailed permissions from the Mac Os?  For example, I was able to use the `attr -l filename.ext` to view extended permissions on files that I saw have a sticky bit '@'. However, I would like to see owner/group permissions from the Mac Os CLI.